# Activate Catalog in Prestashop on every category

Tags: prestashop

I'm new to Prestashop and have used it for two days or so. The issue i'm currently facing is how I can activate the Catalog sidebar (so users can define their search after pricing, fabric etc) when creating new categories. It works fine with demo categories that was made when installing Prestashop. Tried to search on Google and different sites to find a decent solution, but no luck. Do I have to edit any source code? Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In the PrestaShop back-office go to `Modules` -> `Modules`
2. Find the `Layered navigation block` and click `Configure`
3. Find the filter template and click `Edit`
4. Select new categories in `Categories used for this template`
5. Click `Save`
6. Click `Rebuild entire price index`
7. Click `Build attribute index`
8. Click `Build URL index`